# "To run" vs. "for running of"

Tags: grammaticality, gerund-vs-infinitive, to-for

I read this sentence in a book:

> Petrol is needed for running of a car.

I wonder if I could say "Petrol is needed to run a car."

Is the second sentence grammatically correct? If yes, then what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Yes, it is grammatical. And if you ask me it's preferable by a country mile. Easily orders of magnitude less clumsy and more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are grammatically correct.

The first example is using a "[***gerund***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gerund)" of the verb "run" as an object of the preposition "for".

Gerund is:

> A verb form which functions as a noun, in Latin ending in -ndum
>   (declinable), in English ending in -ing (e.g. asking in do you mind my
>   asking you?).

[Oxford English Dictionary]

Even though the first example has the same meaning as the second one, "Petrol is needed to run a car", "***to-infinitive***" is more than sufficient to express what you want and there is no need to rephrase it to a sentence with a preposition "for" and a gerund "running". **Using to-infinitive is more concise.**

BTW, it's better to use "[***drive***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drive)" in place of "run":

> To operate (a wheeled motorized vehicle). 'drive a car'

[Wiktionary]

Comment: I wouldn't use "drive" in this way. "Running" a car, for matters of maintenance and expense, is much more colloquial. *"How can you afford to run a car on your wages?"*  Compare with "running a business".

Comment: @JHCL Based on your logic, you need an insurance policy, engine oil, spare parts, spare tires, etc. to run a car. The OP is using only "petrol" and it is a completely different context from "running" a business.

Comment: You do need insurance etc to run a car. You're the one who wanted him to use a different word, presumably because the meanings are different. Why do you say the context is different?

Comment: @JHCL You drive a car, not run a car like business. Of course, it makes sense to use "run", but I recommended to use "drive" in place of "run". Is it inappropriate? As far as I recall, I didn't use "I ran a car to fill the tank at nearby gas station." in my life and I have been driving a car longer than I can remember.

Comment: [How much does it cost to run a car?](http://www.theaa.com/motoring_advice/motoring_costs.html) (By the way, I've presumed from the use of "petrol" a British English context.)

Comment: @JHCL [Your cost to drive is higher than you think](http://www.forbes.com/sites#/sites/tombarlow/2011/04/25/your-cost-to-drive-is-higher-than-you-think/). Shall we stop here? You didn't answer my question, BTW. You mean you don't use "drive" in BrE?